# How to make an array of objects, spanning a period, combining month numbers with their names?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an array of objects with one object per month, where the array spans a period from a given start month/year to an end month/year. How can I make the object (using the given month and year) to also include the month name?

For example this is my input:

- start date: `11/22`
- end date: `04/23`

How can I make it into this:

```
const dataResult = [
    {id: 1, month: 11, monthName: Nov, year: 2022},
    {id: 2, month: 12, monthName: Dec, year: 2022},
    {id: 3, month: 01, monthName: Jan, year: 2023},
    {id: 4, month: 02, monthName: Feb, year: 2023},
    {id: 5, month: 03, monthName: Mar, year: 2023},
    {id: 6, month: 04, monthName: Apr, year: 2023},
]
```

I try to make use of this reference array:

```
   const monthsWithIds = [
      { id: 1, name: "Jan" },
      { id: 2, name: "Feb" },
      { id: 3, name: "Mar" },
      { id: 4, name: "Apr" },
      { id: 5, name: "May" },
      { id: 6, name: "Jun" },
      { id: 7, name: "Jul" },
      { id: 8, name: "Aug" },
      { id: 9, name: "Sep" },
      { id: 10, name: "Oct" },
      { id: 11, name: "Nov" },
      { id: 12, name: "Dec" }
    ];
```

...but I can't make it work.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What does the API return and what does the ID have to do with the month? In one  array you have ID 1 and Nov, in the other ID 1 and Jan. What did you try?

Comment: your required `dataResult` doesn't need data from an API - a simple loop will get you there

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put all the information, I have a `select` in my `form`, and I store the data using the inputted data.

Comment: I don't think the "algorithm" tag is appropriate here, as it's a straightforward coding question where the efficiency of the code is not an issue. Though not always, the "algorithm" tag normally signifies an optimization problem or a challenge to improve the time and/or space complexity of some operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the start month/year and the end month/year, you can convert those two pairs of numbers to "yearmonth" numbers, i.e. where the year is multiplied by 12 and you add the zero-based month number to it. Iterate from the start yearmonth to the end yearmonth, and translate each of them to the object format you need:

```js
const monthNames = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

function getAllMonths(startYear, startMonth, endYear, endMonth) {
    const start = startYear * 12 + startMonth - 1;
    return Array.from({length: endYear * 12 + endMonth - start}, (_, i) => ({ 
        id: i + 1, 
        month: (i + start) % 12 + 1, 
        monthName: monthNames[(i + start) % 12],
        year: Math.floor((i + start) / 12)
    }));
}

const dataResult = getAllMonths(2022, 11, 2023, 4);
console.log(dataResult);
```